# Logging into Jenkins disables Build History rendering

Tags: java, google-chrome, firefox, jenkins, continuous-integration

I'm experiencing this behavior of Jenkins (browser?) where logging into Jenkins stops rendering the Build History panel content on the left side.  Once logged out - it's visible again.

Using Firerox 42.0 now but the behavior persisted for a while across other versions of it too.  It also readily manifests itself in Chrome.

Deleting cookies helps temporarily, namely until the next build is run.  Then it disappears again.

Logged out:

[image]

Logged in:

[image]

Any insights on how to fix that are appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The builds are hidden because the "+" symbol next to the "trend" link is not clicked. Click on it, and it will turn into a "-" and the jobs will show.

Comment: jtanner, would you happen to know how to make the "-" (and not a "+") setting to be turned on by default upon logon so one doesn't need to explicitly click on it to see the history?  Is there some kind of a configuration that could be tweaked for that or something else of which I need to be made aware?  Thanks.